# Registry Set Value Proxy Only Works 1 Time

Tags: c#, windows, proxy, registry

So This Code Already Work For Setup My Proxy Pac But The Problem is RegKey.SetValue("AutoConfigURL") or RegKey.DeleteValue("AutoConfigURL") only work for only 1 time.

So I need to reRun my apps for delete or set again. 
Even I use Form Closing, if I SetValue value or do something with button first. The Second time it won't work.

Is there something i missing?

```
    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
    public const int INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39;
    public const int INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37;
    bool settingsReturn, refreshReturn;

    public VPNForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConnectionChecker();
    }

    //When Button Click On or Off By Button Text
    private void VPNButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        if (VPNButton.Text == "ON")
        {
            RegKey.SetValue("AutoConfigURL", "mypaclink/proxy.pac");
            settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            if(RegKey.GetValue("AutoConfigURL") != null)
            {
                RegKey.DeleteValue("AutoConfigURL");
            }
            settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }
        RegKey.Close();
        ConnectionChecker();
    }
    //Delete Proxy Setting
    private void VPNForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey RegKey2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
        if (RegKey2.GetValue("AutoConfigURL") != null)
        {
            RegKey2.DeleteValue("AutoConfigURL");
        }
        settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        RegKey2.Close();
    }
    //Check Condition Proxy is ON or OFF
    public void ConnectionChecker()
    {
        RegistryKey RegKey3 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
        if (RegKey3.GetValue("AutoConfigURL") == null)
        {
            VPNButton.Text = "ON";
            ConnectionLabel.Text = "Disconnected";
        }
        else
        {
            VPNButton.Text = "OFF";
            ConnectionLabel.Text = "Connected";
        }
        RegKey3.Close();
    }
```

Edit #1 :

So I find Problem Not Inside my code but My Own PC, Only Mine from 5 PC. Dunno Why, right now I'm trying to upgrade it from Windows 7 to Windows 10. If Somebody know how to find the Problem please tell me, thank's. 
I Use 4 Windows 7 PC and 1 Windows 10 All Works Fine..

Comment: I've copied your code and pasted in to my test application and it works every time when I click the button. I am using Windows 7 and running from a WinForms app.

Comment: really @Coops ? i was trying to make a new project and it still not work second time... Did i miss something in my PC ?

Comment: Try taking out all the logic apart from the stuff to do with the registry, that way you can count all of that out of your thinking. Also it sounds obvious but you need to refresh (F5) regedit.exe in order to show changes that have been made.

Comment: Ah It's work in another PC :( But Not Mine.
For F5 Regedit.exe i already do that, the problem is in "My PC" the button or RegKey.SetValue is only works only for 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Although in the comments you mention that it works on other PCs, for me the logic in the following code seems reversed:

```
if (RegKey3.GetValue("AutoConfigURL") == null)
{
    VPNButton.Text = "ON";
     ConnectionLabel.Text = "Disconnected";
}
else
{
    VPNButton.Text = "OFF";
    ConnectionLabel.Text = "Connected";
}
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (RegKey3.GetValue("AutoConfigURL") != null) // Reversed the check here
{
    VPNButton.Text = "ON";
    ConnectionLabel.Text = "Disconnected";
}
else
{
    VPNButton.Text = "OFF";
    ConnectionLabel.Text = "Connected";
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you but mine already correct... The Problem inside my PC dunno what... i use 5 another PC the exe is works just fine, just mine it's not work... But Well I will try in today...